# Sub-Division Modifier starts glitching

Tags: modeling

My sub-division modifier keeps glitching out like this and makes stuff go crazy[image]

only works for a cube.

Comment: Hello, maybe it's a bug but could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Might be a graphics card issue. Go to Edit > Preferences > Viewport,
then scroll down to "subdivision" and check if "GPU subdivision" is enabled. If it is, try disabling it and see if the issue persists. If the issue goes away when it's disabled it means it's a GPU issue.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati Thanks a lot its now fixed it was a GPU issue. Hella Thanks!!